# Google Colab: How to access Images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I'm not able to run this code in google colab,I have waited 15 minutes, it doesn't give any error but also it doesn't work. This symbol doesn't stop at all.. Do you guys know what might be the problem is?

```
DATADIR ='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/cat-dog/PetImages'
categories =["Cat","Dog"]
training_data =[]

def create_training_data():
    for category in categories: 
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category) 
        class_num =categories.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try: 
                img_arr =cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array =cv2.resize(img_arr, (50,50))
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            
        
create_training_data()
```

[image]

Comment: did you merge your drive with colab?

Comment: yes I did.. I've just tried the same code with for loop only  (I didn't use function) and I was able to see the pictures but somehow when I try to create a function, it doesn't work..

Comment: try passing 'categories' and 'DATADIR ' as a parameter of the function ```create_training_data(categories,DATADIR)```

Comment: unfortunately.. well, I guess I'll use another platform thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount your google drive

Here is how you do it

[Mounting google drive in colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cMmtzM7rYc-cpW0fkRiTRb-ySr2UHf1h)

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is wrong. You need a space between 'Colab' and 'Notebooks'.

```
DATADIR ='/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/cat-dog/PetImages'
```

Comment: Finally, I was able to solve it last night, there is no problem actually.  After   'except Exception as e:'       I've changed   'pass' to    'print(str(e))'    and somehow problem solved it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve it last night, there is no problem actually. After 'except Exception as e:' I've changed 'pass' to 'print(str(e))' and somehow problem solved it works like a charm!

[[image: Here's the solution]]